# How to apply Remove Noise filter in Praat Script?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, praat

I am a beginner of Praat and I need to apply the `Remove noise...` filter on a file using the Praat script.

**My Code:**

```
filePath$ = dirPath$+"/"+fileName$+".wav";
sound = Read from file... 'filePath$'

selectObject: sound

noise_reduction_method = Spectral subtraction
smoothing      = 40

filtered = Remove noise: 0.0, 0.0, 0.025, 80, 1000, smoothing, noise_reduction_method
selectObject: filtered
```

**Error:**

> Unknown symbol << `'` Script line 16 not performed of completed << `noise_reduction_method$ = 'Spectral subtraction'`

I tried a lot to find out the correct way of giving the last argument of this filter but couldn't succeed. Someone please guide me in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last argument to that command is a string, so the variable where you store it must be a string variable. This should work:

```
method$ = "Spectral subtraction"
smoothing = 40
filtered = Remove noise: 0.0, 0.0, 0.025, 80, 1000, smoothing, method$
```

---

#### Bonus: What does the error mean?

The code you posted does not raise the error you reported (so I guess that comes from a previous version of your script).

If you run the code as it is, it will die saying that the `Spectral subtraction` command does not exist. The upper-case `S` tells the interpreter that what follows is a command name, which in Praat can have spaces and any other number of odd characters (as in `Remove noise...`). If it were a lower-case `s` the interpreter would expect a variable name, and also die.

The error you got (about the unknown symbol) is raised if you surround `Spectral subtraction` in single quotes (`'`), which tell the interpreter to interpolate the value of a variable. In this case, the "unknown symbol" is the `Spectral subtraction` variable, which will remain unknown (= you won't be able to define it) because it is illegal (it starts with an upper-case character and has a space in it).